# C++ Amp/Accelerator basic issue in Hello World

Tags: c++, microsoft-accelerator

I am struggling with a pretty basic C++ AMP questions. In fact, rather embarrassingly it is the Hello World example from here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/04/quot-hello-world-quot-in-c-amp.aspx

I have downloaded the sample code, as well as tried writing it from scratch, but when I run it I get the original v[11] array values printed out rather than the text 'Hello World'.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. I am running this on a Lenovo 64 bit Think pad, I have tried building for x64 and for Win32 but still the same results. I have checked that the graphics card supports DirectX and that it is:

DirectX Version: DirectX 11.

If anyone could offer some help that would be brilliant! I have also stepped through the parallel code using the Debugger Type of GPU Only and can see that the AV[] Array_View is being updated...but when it comes to cout'ing the new values I still get the values from the original V array.

Many thanks!

**Update:**

Ok, so I have played around and it works fine in release build but not in debug.....no idea why yet!

Answer (score 0):

Right, have found answer to my own question. I found this on an MSDN blog relating to VS11 but still seems valid for VS12 on Windows 7:

"However, GPU debugging is not supported on Windows 7 (and there is no workaround, other than installing on Windows 8)."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/09/19/vs-11-developer-preview-gotchas-with-c-amp.aspx

Have done this 'work around' (for want of a better term) and it is all fine!